# REST API: How to fetch objects and popular objects, should it be same API or separate API?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

We have several API endpoints like:

/api/cities/ => Fetches all cities in our database. Its an oversimplified example, actually we have around 1k cities.

```
{
         "name": "Chicago",
         "name": "Los Angeles",
         "name": "New York",
         "name": "Phoenix"
}
```

Currently these API returns city list in alphabetic order.

We have new requirement where we need to fetch popular cities at the top, this followed by list in alphabetic order.

JSON Output would look like:

```
{
   "popular"
   {
     "name": "New York",
     "name": "Los Angeles"
   },
   "all"
   {
      "name": "Chicago",
      "name": "Los Angeles",
      "name": "New York",
      "name": "Phoenix"
   }
}
```

How should current APIs be modified to fulfil this:

1. Should we create new API like /api/popularcities/ which would fetch list of popular cities? This way client would call /api/popularcities/ first and then /api/cities/ API.
2. Should we add query string parameter in existing API /api/cities/?fetch=popularall to fetch both popular and all cities.

Or any other thing, this doesn't look like filter attribute as this is actually adding result at the top and not filtering it out.

We do need to repeat popular cities in all city list as this would be binded directly to UI dropdown and requirement is to keep alphabetic ordering intact.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`popular` cities are a way of sorting for the *same* entities.

It shouldn't be a new resource, but a way of querying the same resource sorted differently to get the needed entries.

I would use a query for that: `?sort=popular`.

Comment: Its not even actually a sort as the same ids get repeated again in all listings but its a good suggestion, can be considered.

Comment: Why would you fetch both in `all` and `popular` ? What's the use case ?

Comment: Because these would directly get bind in dropdown, and in case user do not see the popular list, we want to let him find it in alphabetic city list too.

Comment: I actually don't understand the concept of `popular cities at the top, this followed by list in alphabetic order`. Either the list is popular sorted, either not :). If popularity let's say is equal for a city, the alphabet sorting can be done. But this can be abstracted in the same endpoint, by delivering only the popular entries.

Comment: I have edited the question, this case is not pure sorting case. Hope its clear from 2 json examples in the question. Let me know if there is any doubt.

Comment: Is the requirement that the same json should contain `popular` and `all` ?

Comment: Clients need popular cites + all cities(in alphabetic order). Be it in same json through one API OR through two separate APIs exposed to client i.e. /api/cities/ and /api/popularcities

Comment: I don't understand the need of sending same entries twice in the same response. I would still return the list in the popular order; the response you show in the question is pretty strange, as every entry has popularity, not only the 3rd and 4th. So order by popularity, and in case you need everything again sorted alphabetically, one extra call, without the sorting parameter (defaults to alphabetical).

Comment: @loan: I have edited the question. I have given real example now, I believe it would give better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use both endpoint, a endpoint like as shortcut of api fetch all with order by popular.

1. /cities?sort=popular
2. /popular_cities